# Is there a mass version of Protection from Energy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I could have sworn that there was a spell somewhere in 3.5 that gave the effect of *protection from energy* to multiple targets, but I can't seem to find it.  I've checked the PHB, SC, and several other splatbooks, but I'm not finding any mention of a mass *protection from energy* spell.  I know that there's a *protection from energy, communal* spell in Pathfinder, but I can't find it in 3.5.

Does such a spell exist in an official 3.5 product, and if so, where is it?

Comment: You may be thinking of Resist Energy, Mass?

Comment: I don't think I am.  I can find that one, I just thought I remembered there being a mass protection from energy as well.

Comment: @Ruut *Resist energy* is quite different from *protection from energy*, though I do think that *mass resist energy* is probably the reason they never bothered with *mass protection from energy*.

Comment: If it's any consolation, an effect like the spell *protection from energy* can be simultaneously tied to the spell *hallow* or *unhallow*. How that works is in the DM's hands, but if there's enough warning that might be sufficient for the villagers huddled in the church to survive the dragon's breath weapon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’m not *absolutely certain* that [imarvintpa.com’s spell finder](http://imarvintpa.com/dndLive/FindSpell.php) has every sourcebook ever, but if it’s missing any, I don’t know what they are. It’s extremely thorough.

On a search for `*protection from energy*`, it finds only *protection from energy* itself. I therefore conclude that no *mass protection from energy*, *legion’s protection from energy*, *communal protection from energy*, or any other such thing was ever printed.

The combination of the Chain Spell feat from *Complete Arcane* and the [Reach Spell metamagic feat from *Deities and Demigods*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#reachSpell) or [Arcane Reach high arcana from the archmage](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/archmage.htm#arcaneReach) can allow you to apply *protection from energy* to many creatures at once, if you wish. Ridiculously expensive, though; if you use both feats rather than Arcane Reach, it turns *protection from energy* into a 9th-level spell.

Or just back-port Pathfinder’s; it’s not an unreasonable spell by any means.

Comment: Could you combine Arcane Reach with a Rod of Chain Spell to lower the cost?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Sure; there are numerous other ways that you could do so, as well. Not really on topic to go through them all.